# Fail to install mongodb properly on digitalocean

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, digital-ocean

I am trying to install mongo on DigitalOcean but am getting this error:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-shell but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: mongodb-org-tools but it is not going to be installed
           E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I followed this [documentation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04)

My steps:

1. sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv
   0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6
2. echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu
   xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse" | sudo tee
   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list
3. sudo apt-get update
4. sudo apt-get install mongodb-org

But when I used this command "sudo apt-get install mongodb " it install successfully but throw this error "Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found." when I run this command sudo **systemctl start mongod**

Comment: You can try `sudo apt upgrade`. It may help. Your db server version is very old. Follow this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/

Answer (score 0):

I finally installed it by following these steps:

1. sudo apt-get remove --purge mongodb-org
2. sudo apt-get autoremove

Then I followed the official [docs](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04) to re-install and it works fine.